# Test a pull request created from a forked repo

Tags: git, github

Let's say I own the site "stackoverflow". It's at `github.com/stackoverflow/main-site`.

Now Jimmy creates a fork of the repo, `github.com/jimmy/main-site`.

Jimmy then creates a pull request and submits it to my original repo. Jimmy didn't give me access to the fork though.

**How can I test the PR locally?**

Github gives these instructions:

```
Step 1. From your project repository, checkout a new branch and test the changes.

git checkout -b sweet-awesome-changes master
```

That works fine. I've just created a branch `sweet-awesome-changes` locally.

Next Github says this:

```
git pull git@github.com:jimmy/main-site.git sweet-awesome-changes
```

But when I do that, I get an error that the repository isn't found:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What should I do?

Comment: What you want is to check out *their* code, not yours, so add them as a remote and the checkout that remote's branch - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote and note the "further reading" link, too.

Comment: Thanks Mike, trying now.  So are Github's instructions wrong, or just incomplete?

Comment: You add them as remote and then you check out their branch, from their remote: `git remote add jimmy https://github.com/jimmy/main-sit`, then a `git fetch jimmy` to make sure you know what branches he has, and then `git checkout jimmy/their-PR-branch`, done. You are now in detached head mode and can test their branch as much as you like. Don't pull/merge/etc, just check out the branch. Done.

Comment: Alright it looks like the author's repo was private. Github's instructions work without any extra steps for adding remotes once access was given.